# MVVM: Handling list item navigation with keyboard in Windows 8

Tags: mvvm, windows-8, keyboard, navigation, mvvm-light

I am totally new to Windows 8 development and I am now facing an issue mixing touch and keyboard navigation using MVVM Light.

So I have a list of view models in a grid view and whenever one of those is selected, navigation to the selected view model is activated. This works totally fine with touch or a mouse, but with a keyboard it can get really confusing. Indeed, the natural behavior would be to navigate the list with the arrows and hit enter when I want to display the item, but here instead, navigation will be activated when simply changing item with the arrow keys which is really confusing for the user.

So how could I do so the navigation could be activated on selection with touch and mouse and with a combination of selection and enter key with the keyboard?

Here is the code I use.

ViewModel:

```
public ReleaseViewModel SelectedRelease
{
    get
    {
        return selectedRelease;
    }
    set
    {
        if(selectRelease != value)
        {
            selectedRelease = value;
        }

        // Navigation code here
    }
}
```

View:

```
<GridView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Releases}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ReleaseTemplate}"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemStyle}"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    Grid.Row="2"
    Padding="116,0,40,46"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRelease, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I finally found is to use some code behind. But instead of directy navigating from the UI I kept navigation logic in the view models.

So I simply hooked up the ItemClick event from the GridView and in the event handler I casted the Page data context to my view model and then I simply executed the command from the view model. This is not easy to maintain but it surely preserve the separation of concerns of MVVM.

```
private void GridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    MyViewModel vm = (MyViewModel)this.DataContext;

    if(vm.NavigateToSelectionCommand.CanExecute(null))
    {
        vm.NavigateToSelectionCommand.Execute(e.ClickedItem);
    }
}
```

Still I hope a cleaner and more maintainable solution will come up with time.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, coding with the MVVM pattern does not mean that everything code-related should be done in the model. Operations which is related UI beaviors (like navigation) should still be done in the view (the codebehind), by using the available events from the control. Like the GridView's events mouse and keyboard events.

Many may not agree with me on that, but after working by the MVVM pattern for several years in both WPF and Silverlight, I must say that a good combination between the UI-behavior (view) and the control's logic/functionability (model), you will also be forced to put several stuff which concerns the UI only to the codebehind. At least, this is my opinion.

What you could do is to create a class which inherits GridView (let's call it MyDataGrid).
Then you can use the OnKeyDown override and have the navigation go vertica when pressing enter.
You can actually make the MyDataGrid look and behave "out-of-the-box" just like you want so there are no extra code if you want to use the same grid behavior another place in your app (or another app).

Comment: I am originally a WPF developper and migrating to this new platform actually made me wonder if the navigation is actually a UI concern or an application logic concern? It is part of the application workflow but at the same time is a UI movement.

I actually wondered about getting a bit less extreme about MVVM pattern and give navigation back to the UI (like in the default templates).

About the GridView no need to extend it because handling the Click event actually reacts uniformly to the keyboard/touch/mouse natural interactions, but of course it is not compatible with MVVM.

Comment: True. It's difficult to separate what should be UI and not, because that is in some cases a definition that varies from person to person.
I usually say it's a matter of UI when it comes to HOW things are selected or gets the value. If it's double-clicked, single-clicked, button-clicked or tabbed and used keyboard/enter. That really doesn't matter to the model. The model will only concern what happens when it's actually selected. Not how.
I'm not a designer. If a designer comes up with a better solution on how the user whould work, I would like to not having to change the model. Only the view.

Comment: There IS a case to be made for managing the state of the UI from the workflow/navigation point of view. This area of concern is generally addressed with an ApplicationController pattern. Laurent calls this a "NavigationService" in his examples, but it's pretty close to the same thing. The ApplicationController can be as simple as a switch statement to as sophisticated as a full Finite State Machine. The main thing is that the View and/or the ViewModel will send a message (or trigger an event) for the ApplicationController, which will then navigate the UI to the new View.